# Membership test results different with list and csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

I get different results if I check for membership with a list than with a csv.reader object.
The below uses the unittest module.

csv.reader test for membership

```
with open("file.tab", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    self.assertTrue(['1', '2', '3', '4'] in reader)
    self.assertTrue(['2', '3', '4', '5'] in reader)
    self.assertTrue(['3', '4', '5', '6'] in reader)
```

list test for membership

```
with open("file.tab", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    reader = [record for record in reader]
    self.assertTrue(['1', '2', '3', '4'] in reader)
    self.assertTrue(['2', '3', '4', '5'] in reader)
    self.assertTrue(['3', '4', '5', '6'] in reader)
```

I know that file.tab contains entries for the three records I'm testing for, but the third assert comes up "False is not true" when using csv.reader and passes when using a list.

csv.reader is a generator; the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects) don't explicitly say, but since I can exhaust it I think that means it's a generator. My thinking was this might be the reason, but the following test prints nothing but true:

```
x = xrange(5)
for m in range(5):
    for n in range(5):
        print m in x
        print n in x
```

Which makes me think that there are no problems testing for membership with a generator.

Why does the third assert statement evaluate differently when I use a csv.reader than when I use a list?

Comment: `reader = [record for record in reader]` can be rewritten as `reader = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t'))` just as an aside

Comment: `xrange` actually returns [an immutable sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange), not a generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had some bad luck there-- `xrange` isn't actually a generator, but a special type of its own which behaves lazily, and so can fool you into thinking it's one.

```
>>> x = xrange(10)
>>> 5 in x
True
>>> 5 in x
True
```

but

```
>>> it = iter(range(10))
>>> 5 in it
True
>>> 5 in it
False
```

So your logic was right: the `reader` instance can be exhausted, but the list can't, which is why membership tests can return different answers, depending on the contents.  Note though that membership tests may short-circuit, and so they don't have to exhaust in case of a positive result:

```
>>> it = iter(range(10))
>>> 3 in it
True
>>> next(it)
4
```

Comment: Aha! Good to know about xrange.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, csv.reader is a generator and `in` iterates while it finds the value. As DSM demonstrated.

In your CSV file the order of the rows is different than in your tests. Your tests will pass if you change the order:

```
>>> def fake_reader():
...     yield ['1', '2', '3', '4']
...     yield ['2', '3', '4', '5']
...     yield ['3', '4', '5', '6']

>>> reader = fake_reader()
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4'] in reader
True
>>> ['2', '3', '4', '5'] in reader
True
>>> ['3', '4', '5', '6'] in reader
True
```

And it fails if the order is different:

```
>>> def fake_reader():
...     yield ['1', '2', '3', '4']
...     yield ['3', '4', '5', '6'] # changed order
...     yield ['2', '3', '4', '5']

>>> reader = fake_reader()
>>> ['1', '2', '3', '4'] in reader # reads one row
True
>>> ['2', '3', '4', '5'] in reader # reads two rows!
True
>>> ['3', '4', '5', '6'] in reader # there are no more rows to read
False
```